# Is there a way in which we can check for presence of data in application.properties file in Spring Boot Project before the tomcat server starts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am writing a Spring Boot project to Run a Cloud Config Server and 3 Micro-services to run as a Client.

I would want to check availability of all properties in application.properties or yaml file before starting the tomcat server.

We already have a similar one for Database Startup Validation, but here I am trying to achieve the same for Property file availability.

Can someone let me know or suggest possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add whatever you want to add in application.properties / yaml file and then access the property and its value in SpringBoot Application like this.

I think this could help you.

> application.properties

```
property1=true
property2=false
property3=abc
property5=1223243
```

and in SpringBoot Application

> TestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication{

    @Value("${property1}")
    private boolean property1

    @Value("${property2}")
    private boolean property2

    @Value("${property3}")
    private String property3

    @Value("${property5}")
    private int property5

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

 }
```

[UPDATE]

If we are agreed to create a Pre-Script that run before tomcat startup then

Using the following code snippet we can parse the `application.properties` file and create object and then loop through the length of properties file and check the Key Value pairs

```
FileReader reader=new FileReader("application.properties");  
  
Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);  
  
System.out.println(p.getProperty("user"));  
System.out.println(p.getProperty("password"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I would want to access all of the properties and validate them at once without having to instantiate them every time in the class file. Can you please suggest any other ways for this ?

Comment: have a look: https://reflectoring.io/validate-spring-boot-configuration-parameters-at-startup/ I think this will help

Comment: nope :( I would want to validate / check if the property file has any value and not the data type / other features. I had a chance to review the same website earlier, but my use case is to check presence of property in the prop file.

Comment: Alright So you want to check whether a `key` is present in `application.properties` file or not?

Comment: Could you please help me to understand how you are doing this in  `Database Startup Validation` ??

Comment: Yeah. I want to check if a key is present on the Application properties/YAML file. But we cannot achieve this with Database StartupValidator as it is specific to any DB connections. So I tried using Environment Class Implementation to check if we are getting the values, but unfortunately it doesnt expose all the properties directly. I am trying to access these via BootStrapProperties at the moment.